# Recovering a concatenated disk (ccd)

Tags: filesystems, freebsd

I need to recover data from an old filesystem, which was located on two small (by today's standards) drives -- using a concatenated disk driver (known as [ccd](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ccd(4)) in FreeBSD).

I have the drives online (no disk errors) and have already dumped their images.

My problem is, I do not remember the interleave factor I used 10 years ago... How would I recover that? The [scan_ffs](https://man.openbsd.org/scan_ffs.8)  finds some old superblocks on each image, but those aren't usable until I properly interleave them together again.

Are there any tell-tale signs of ccd, that would help me detect the interleave value I used?

*Update*: Using some tools I was able "recover" some files from one of the drives -- including MPEG-files, which, predictably, have regular holes in them -- `ffplay` is doing its best to play them, but complains about *lots* of errors and the streams constantly stutter.

I think, by measuring the sizes of the holes, I'll be able to figure out the interleave. Can they be measured, though?

Comment: Have you try to dump the ccd config `ccdconfig -g`?

Comment: Thanks, @RomeoNinov, I just tried that option -- no, it does not help. It simply reports the currently-used configuration, which is no indication of the validity of the filesystem(s) on top of it...

Comment: Have you looked at [geom(8)](https://manpage.me/?geom)? That should provide quite a bit of detail on what you're looking for.